# Evaluating usefulness of estimations of a parameter for different distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, sample, geometric-distribution

If I had a sample of size n and wished to estimate some parameter, say p for two different distributions from the produced sample what would be required to determine which was more useful?

Assume the two distributions are Geometric and Binomial

Comment: Useful in what way?

Comment: Accuracy in predicting p

Comment: You could estimate the confidence interval for both these parameters and choose the one with the smallest one (smallest standard error). As for the accuracy of the mean... this should be unbiased so there is no real way to tell which one is "closer".

Comment: Your question is still unclear. "Accuracy in predicting p" is problematic because $p$ means different things in relation to the same observations if you're choosing between binomial and geometric. How are they to be considered comparable?

Answer (score 0):

1st calculate **Mean** and **Variance** numerically then plug available information in to formula of mean and variance. Further, simple mathematical calculation provides values of parameter for that specific data.
Like mean of Geometric Dist is $$\frac{1}{p}$$. so reciprocal of mean is value of **p**, and so on.

Comment: Surely this is for a population, the question requires the evaluation of a sample and determining which sample is more informative in regards to estimating parameter p

Comment: you can use unbiased estimators for this purpose.